# Python: Join two dataframes based on hour and nearest minute of date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have two dataframes with different dates as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['2022-01-01 00:37:57', '2022-01-01 03:49:12', '2022-01-01 09:30:11'], columns = ['price'])
df1['price'] = [10,13,12]
df1.index = df1.index.rename('date')
df1:
                        price
date                      
2022-01-01 00:37:57     10
2022-01-01 03:49:12     13
2022-01-01 09:30:11     12 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=['2022-01-01 00:35:00', '2022-01-01 00:47:00', '2022-01-01 00:56:12', '2022-01-01 03:45:00', '2022-01-01 03:50:32',
                        '2022-01-01 09:29:20', '2022-01-01 09:31:21'], columns=['price'])
df2['price'] = [3000,3210, 2999, 3001, 3027, 3021, 3002]
df2.index = df2.index.rename('date')
df2:
                      price
date                      
2022-01-01 00:35:00   3000
2022-01-01 00:47:00   3210
2022-01-01 00:56:12   2999
2022-01-01 03:45:00   3001
2022-01-01 03:50:32   3027
2022-01-01 09:29:20   3021
2022-01-01 09:31:21   3002
```

I want to left join df1 with df2, `df1.join(df2,how='left')`, on the hour and nearest minute to get the following:

```
df:
                        price_x price_y
date
2022-01-01 00:37:57     10      3000
2022-01-01 03:49:12     13      3210
2022-01-01 09:30:11     12      3021
```

So for example, the last row left joined on the date "2022-01-01 09:29:20" since it is closest to "2022-01-01 09:30:11".

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`pd.merge_asof()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof) (assuming the index of DateTime type and sorted):

```py
print(
    pd.merge_asof(
        df1,
        df2,
        left_index=True,
        right_index=True,
        direction="nearest",
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
                     price_x  price_y
date                                 
2022-01-01 00:37:57       10     3000
2022-01-01 03:49:12       13     3027
2022-01-01 09:30:11       12     3021
```

Answer (score 0):

Anrej Kesely gave a great response. I'm going to guess that pandas does it more efficiently than myself. I don't have the reputation to add a comment to clarify your question. However, if you were looking for the nearest date in df2 that occurs before the date in df1. This code will work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['2022-01-01 00:37:57', '2022-01-01 03:49:12', '2022-01-01 09:30:11'], columns = ['price'])
df1['price'] = [10,13,12]
df1.index = df1.index.rename('date')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=['2022-01-01 00:35:00', '2022-01-01 00:47:00', '2022-01-01 00:56:12', '2022-01-01 03:45:00', '2022-01-01 03:50:32',
                        '2022-01-01 09:29:20', '2022-01-01 09:31:21'], columns=['price'])
df2['price'] = [3000,3210, 2999, 3001, 3027, 3021, 3002]
df2.index = df2.index.rename('date')
df2 = df2.reset_index()
display(df1)
def min_diff(date, df):
    min_diff = -18000000
    min_index = -1
    for i in range(len(df)):
        difference = int(datetime.strptime((df['date'][i]),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()) - int(datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp())
        if difference < 0:
            if (difference > min_diff):
                min_diff = difference
                min_index = i
    return min_index

print(df2.loc[min_diff(df1['date'][0], df2)])   
df1['Price from 2'] = ''
for i in range(len(df1)):
    df1.loc[i,'Price from 2'] = df2.loc[min_diff(df1['date'][i], df2),'price']
display(df1)
```

This displays the following,

```
                  date  price Price from 2
0  2022-01-01 00:37:57     10         3000
1  2022-01-01 03:49:12     13         3001
2  2022-01-01 09:30:11     12         3021
```

If you were looking for just the nearest date without concern for direction. @Anrej Kesely gave a great answer. Hope either of us helped!

Comment: Well, I looked at the documentation for pandas.merge_asof it defaults to backward which is what I implemented in my answer. So, even if you wanted to go backward following his advice would get you almost there. *insert self deprecating wasted my time joke*